# Design of Duplicative Nested Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to design a Rails 5 application for a university. As a first step, I tried to design 'department' related models (units in general), such as faculties, vocational schools, institues, undergraduate programs, graduate programs etc. However I found the case a bit more complex than I expected.

Here is how the real world data have structured for my situation:

```
University ->
  -> Academies
      -> Undergraduate Programs
      -> Divisions
          -> Undergraduate Programs
          -> Departments
  -> Vocational Schools
      -> Undergraduate Programs
      -> Divisions
          -> Undergraduate Programs
  -> Faculties
      -> Undergraduate Programs
      -> Departments
      -> Divisions
          -> Undergraduate Programs
          -> Departments
```

You can think of all these models as nested has_many relations. For example a university has_many faculties. A faculty has_many departments and has_many divisions. A faculty division has_many departments etc. Each level behaves like a new has_many, theoretically.

As an example, take a look to Faculty. Departments can directly be under the Faculty, or they can be under the Division. But still, they are Departments no matter where they are located, and they will behave exactly the same way. In other words, creating different models for Departments located under Faculty and Departments located under Divisions will be quite duplicative and nonsense for my situation. Same can also be said for Undergraduate Programs. And I am looking for a better alternative.

I thought about polymorphism at first, but I am not sure if it is the proper way to solve this problem. And the question is, what would be the best approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you need specific information for some of your models (departments, divisions, programs, academies, schools? Any other different model not shown? Or maybe you want a flexible approach and be able to add new types of children.

Comment: Yes Pablo, all these models will have their custom methods and behaviours. As you said, in the future there may be additional child models too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a combination of Single Table Inheritance (STI) and polymorphism:

```
# in lack of a better name
class UniversityUnit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :university

  has_many :undergraduate_programs,
    as: :unit

  has_many :divisions, 
    as: :unit

  has_many :departments, 
    through: :divisions

  has_many :division_undergraduate_programs,
     through: :divisions
end

class Academy < UniversityUnit

end

class VocationalSchool < UniversityUnit

end

class Faculity < UniversityUnit

end

class Division
  belongs_to :unit, polymorphic: true 
  has_many :departments, as: :unit
end

class UndergraduateProgram
  belongs_to :unit, polymorphic: true 
  has_many :departments, as: :unit
end

class Department
  belongs_to :unit, polymorphic: true
end
```

The trickiest part will be dealing with the join/ eagerloading issues that come with polymorphism and traversing up the graph.

Or use Multiple Table Inheritance instead and declare each of the tree nodes as a generic type but with a association to the specific type:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :specific_type, polymorpic: true
  belongs_to :organization, optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Organization'
  has_many :grand_children, 
    through: :children,
    source: :children
end

class Academy < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :organization, as: :specific_type
end

class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :organization, as: :specific_type
end
```

This is for example how Drupal works on the backend.

This kind of self joining association lets you create trees of infinite depth without adding additional complexity for each level. You also avoid a lot of the pitfalls of polymorphism when it comes to eager loading and joining associated records.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism is your best bet. Each of the Schools, Divisions and Departments are all the same thing.  They have a parent and they have multiple children, and they probably have multiple Students and Faculty. Depending on what kind of business logic you intend to implement, you may be able to get away with just categorizing them by name or type and just using a tree to capture the structure.

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Department', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Department'
  has_many :staff
  has_many :students
end
```

Instead of managing all of that yourself though, I'd recommend looking at a library to handle it for you. Something like [Ancestery](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) would be a good starting point.

I don't believe your model needs to be complex. A single object should work just fine for Schools, Divisions, and Departments, unless they each have unique business logic. And even then, if you give the object a type, you might be able to put that business logic in their own models.